# Get data from Observable every x Seconds, with Start and Stop buttons

Tags: angular, rxjs

i have an **Observable** to call every **x** seconds.

and two buttons named **Start** and **Stop** to control the observable.

i want to Stop the process and unsubscribe when user pressed **Stop** button and start getting data each **x** seconds after pressing **Start**

so far i have :

```
public subscription: Subscription;
public isLoading: boolean = false;
public isStopped: boolean = true;

// Start Getting Data
getData() {
    this.isStopped = false;
    this.isLoading = true;

    this.subscription = this.proxy.InternetUserRwaits(model).pipe(
        repeatWhen(completed => {
            return completed.pipe(
                tap(_ => this.isLoading = false),
                delay(this.interval * 1000),
                tap(_ => this.isLoading = this.isStopped ? false : true),
            );
        }),
    )
    .subscribe(
        result => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            // ... rest of code
        },
        error => console.error(error)
    );
}

// Stop Getting Data
stopGettingData() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    this.isStopped = true;
    this.isLoading = false;
}
```

but its not working after the first stop

Comment: getting data from where? What is the source of your data? If it's an observable, when and how many times does it emit?

Comment: yes it is an observable that emits whole data at once each time. i want to call observable every x seconds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to start with an interval observable, and every time it emits, subscribe to your service observable which gets the data:

```
this.subscription = interval(5000).pipe(
  tap(() => this.isLoading = true)
  switchMap(() => myService.loadData())
  tap(() => this.isLoading = false)
  finalize(() => this.isLoading = false)
).subscribe(data => this.result = data);
```

Comment: thanks its working now. i just need to do some tests to see what happens on timeout or error. does it call the service observable repeatedly on this situations ?

Comment: If you don't understand what this code does, then you really, really need to. And the best way to do that is to read the documentation of the functions being used. On error, the error propagates. If you need to keep repeating even if one loading fails, you would need to use the catchError operator on the observable returned by `myService.loadData()`.

Comment: yeah i'm not good at rxjs. the code is simple and looks working good.

Comment: Only changes I'd make would be to a) remove the subscription variable and have a `destroy$: Subject<boolean>()` that emits in `ngOnDestroy`, allowing you to add a `takeUntil(this.destroy$)` to the pipe, and b) move the logic in the `subscribe` callback to a `tap`.

Answer (score 0):

We're going to need more information..

Are you trying to stop the flow for each subscriber? or stop the flow to all subscribers of the Observable?

Here's the steps I would take to achieve for the latter.

1. Create an `Angular Service`, with a `BehaviourSubject` and a timer
   function.
2. At each timer interval, call the `.next()` function of the
   `BehaviourSubject`, passing the data you want to pass.
3. Add two functions, `Start()` and `Stop()` to the service, and use an if statement in the timer function to control the calls to the `.next()` function.
4. In your child component(s?), import your service and subscribe to the `BehaviourSubject`.
5. Call the `Start()` and `Stop()` functions on the on the service to control the distribution of data.